# Remove data row from table with button

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to remove data from my database with a "Delete"-button.

My data is displayed in a table and I added an extra column with a button, which should delete ONLY the data from that row. The website is running on Wordpress with a custom built plugin.

This is how I create and fill the table:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Fornavn</th>
            <th>Efternavn</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Virksomhed</th>
            <th>Fjern</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <?php if ($members_array){
        foreach ($members_array as $member) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $member['firstname'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $member['lastname'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $member['email'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $member['company'] ?></td>
                <form id="cancel_form_admin" method="POST" action="">
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Fjern" name="fjern_kursist"/>
                    </td>
                </form>
            </tr>
    <?php }
            }?>                         
</table>
```

(this table is only visible for admins)

I have the remove-function working on a separate website, where the user has to fill in their email address and it will get removed from the database.

I tried copying the function and pasting it here, but the problem I run into is that it removes all data from the table that is connected to that course_ID, and not only the email address from the row I click the button.

This is the code I'm using to remove a user from the database:

```
$email = $member['email']; 

if(isset($_POST['fjern_kursist'])) {
    /*delete participant from db*/
    $delete_query = "DELETE from ";
    $delete_query .= $wpdb->prefix . "member_data ";
    $delete_query .= "WHERE email = '" . $email . "' AND course_id = '" . get_the_ID() . "'";
    $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( $delete_query ));
}
```

How do I fix my code, so it only removes data from the row I press the "Fjern" (delete) button and not from every row that has a "fjern"-button?

Comment: create a hidden field for ID. because ID identify which record to delete.

Comment: It's actually the email that decides which row is removed. Or am I misunderstanding your comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to include the identity of the member in the form,

```
<input type=hidden name="member_id" value="<? echo intval($member['id']); ?>">
```

Then can use it in the delete query

```
$delete_query .= "WHERE member_id = " . intval($_POST['member_id']). " AND course_id = '" . get_the_ID() . "'";
```

Using intval as a quick way to avoid both SQL and HTML injection. Which you really need to learn about. (in for strings like the email, should be using something like htmlentities, and for for sql, using real prepared queries, or the quote function of what ever db library you using.

Comment: if you dont want to pass id, around like this, can pass the email in the same way (being careful to escape the email like mentioned)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The people that sign up, don't have an account on the website, so they don't have an ID (or I don't know what it's called at least). However, by passing the email through the hidden input, it works, so marking as the right answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try hidden field ID like below:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Fornavn</th>
            <th>Efternavn</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Virksomhed</th>
            <th>Fjern</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <?php if ($members_array){
        foreach ($members_array as $member) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $member['firstname'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $member['lastname'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $member['email'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $member['company'] ?></td>
                <form id="cancel_form_admin" method="POST" action="">
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Fjern" name="fjern_kursist"/>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo  $member['id'] ?>" name="member_id"/>

                    </td>
                </form>
            </tr>
    <?php }
            }?>                         
</table>
```